# Erased Macintosh HD - Data. Now can't login

Tags: macos, mac, disk-utility

This all started because I was trying to clean install a Macbook Pro that someone sold me.

They gave me the password to log into the computer under their profile so I could clean install it.

I started the process of erasing Macintosh HD so I could reinstall macOS (Catalina).

While trying to erase, I was prompted for the previous user's password for their Gmail so they could be logged out of Find My Mac. The profile password didn't work for this.

I accidentally erased Macintosh HD - Data, and now the computer won't let me log in at all.

Here's what happens:  I turn the Macbook on, it goes to the login screen like normal.

[image]

I enter the password that worked before, but now this happens.

[image]

And when I hit a key, I am sent back into the login screen.

[image]

And there's no way out of this loop except to go into Recovery Mode.

When I go into Disk Utility, this is what Macintosh HD looks like.

[image]

When I try to mount the Macintosh HD, I get this error.

[image]

I tried resetting the NVRAM, I tried doing internet recovery on Macintosh HD - Data. Nothing changed.

Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This all went wrong because whoever sold you it should have done all this before selling it… :\ They sold you a machine that's still locked. We need to know precisely what Mac it is - age plays a big part in this; how well it's locked. See https://support.apple.com/HT201065

Comment: Oh shoot. That would be helpful wouldn't it. MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Comment: That's newer than my experience could answer, I'm afraid - but will have the latest security implementation. I'll have to let someone more familiar with the newer security structures take over. Wish you luck :)

Comment: Why do you need to log into it in order to "factory-reset" it?  Erase the DRIVE, not one or the other of the two volumes, and reinstall the OS.  Now, if it's still activation-locked, that's another problem, but nothing in your posting has anything to do with reisntalling the OS, it's all just random poking with your eyes closed.

Comment: When you try to erase the drives it asks you to input the password? I was just trying to demonstrate what changed after I accidentally erased the Macintosh HD - Data in hopes that it would be helpful.

Comment: Also? I'm here for help, not condescension. So maybe skip that part.

Comment: ⌘ + R recovery mode (Internet Recovery) will restore the OS that originally came on your Mac, not the currently installed one.

Comment: If you couldn't erase the drive without the password, then for any machine with an unknown password, the machine would be forever unusable (leaving aside Activation Lock/Firmware Lock issues).  Run Disk Utility, in the View menu choose to show all devices, highlight the top level, choose Erase, follow the prompts.  Then reinstall the OS.

Comment: Jessifer: The Disk Utility images you posted only show the volumes. If you press the `⌘2` key combination, then the drives should appear. Highlight the internal drive, then press the `Erase` button.